# Implementing an ADT list by using array-based linked list

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I am trying to implement an array-based linked list which has to be orderer alphabetically. I have the code to insert and node so far but wanted to check if i that is correct and if someone can help me write a main method to display elements of the list. Below is the code i have so far.

```
package listpackage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ArrayLL {
private int MAX_CAP = 100;
private ANode[] list;
private int size;

public ArrayLL(){
    list = new ANode[MAX_CAP];
    list[list.length-1] = new ANode(null, -1);
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length-1; i++){
        list[i] = new ANode(null, i+1);
    }
    size = 0;
}

public void addElem(String s) throws IOException{
    if(size == 0){
        ANode a = new ANode(s, -1);
        list[0] = a;
        size++;
    }else if(size == MAX_CAP + 1){
        throw new IOException("List is full");
    }else{
        ANode a = list[0];
        for(int i = 0; i< size; i++){
            if(a.getData().compareTo(s)>0){
                ANode b = new ANode(s,i+1);
                for(int j = size; j > i; j--){
                    list[j] = list[j+1];
                }
                list[i] = b;
                size++;
                break;
            }else{
                ANode c = new ANode(s,-1);
                list[size+1] = c;
            }
        }
    }
}

public int getSize(){
    return size;
}

}

class ANode{
private String data;
private int link;

public ANode(String d, int l){
    data =  d;
    link = l;
}

public String getData(){
    return data;
}

public int getLink(){
    return link;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're facing?

Comment: See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for code reviews.

Comment: I am getting an exception when i try to insert a node at the head when array has elements.

Comment: Also how can i print the elements of the list?

Answer (score 0):

To print the elements of the list you need to iterate it to see the contents.

```
for(Object obj : list) {
  System.out.println(obj);
}
```

also your Object needs to have `.toString()` overriden.

hope this helps

Comment: My object is ANode and it has a getData() method, but now when i try this  
ArrayLL all = new ArrayLL();
  for(ANode a : all){
 System.out.println(a.getData());
  }

it tells me that it can only iterate over an array or an instance of Java.lang.Iteratable

Comment: Ok i managed to display it. I just realized i am storing the array of elements in an object.so i wrote a method getList that will return the actual list of nodes. The object itself is not an array. its just like a container for the array.

Comment: the code does not update the index. of the node like this. how can i set the index of each node to the next one and set the index of the last element to -1.